# Can't Get Photos to Work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am having all kinds of trouble doing a simple task, displaying a photo as part of a result set for each one. I'm pretty new to Rails in general, coming from another language where I can do this in seconds.

The `@photo` query finds 0 records even though multiple records for photos are in the DB matching the property ID.

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here are my relevant files:

**app/controllers/properties_controller.rb**:

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController

  ......

  def all
    # gets all of the properties and uses will_paginate
    @properties = Property.paginate(page: params[:page])

    # should get the first positioned photo matching the results in the @properties query
    @photos = Photo.where(:property_id => @properties.map(&:id)).order("position").first
  end

  # ......

end
```

**app/models/property.rb**:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :listing_type
  belongs_to :property_type
  belongs_to :status

  has_many :photos

  # ......

end
```

**app/models/photo.rb**:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :photoname, PhotoUploader

  belongs_to :property

  acts_as_list scope: :property_id

  validates :photoname, presence: true
  validates :property_id, presence: true
end
```

**details.html.erb**:

```
<% @properties.reverse_each do |property| %>
  <div class="item col-md-4">
    <div class="image">
      <%= link_to property_path(property) do %>
        <span class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Details</span>
      <% end %>
      <%= image_tag(property) %>
    </div>

  # ......

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `has_many` realtion in the `Property`, you have to just access to the relation of the property to read all teh photoes:

```
photo = @property.photos.order("position").first
```

Well if you need to grab all the photoes of properties, use include to properties grab:

```
@properties = Property.includes(:photos).paginate(page: params[:page]).reverse
```

the include is needed to [avoid `N + 1` problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), then try replacing it with a first photo:

```
@photos = @properties.map { |pr| pr.photos.order("position").first }
```

Mpve `reverse` to controller, and to use `@photos` along with `@properties` use index:

```
<% @properties.each.with_index do |property, i| %>
   #...
   <%= image_tag(@photos[i]) %>
<- end >
```

**NOTE** that the code selecting an image `pr.photos...` be better moved to a *decorator* (see gem `draper`).

Comment: When I do this from your comment above: @photo = Photo.where(property_id: @property.id).order("position").limit(1), I get an error ... NoMethodError in PropertiesController#all ... undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: When I do: @photo = @property.photos.order("position").first I get an error ... NoMethodError in PropertiesController#all ... undefined method `photos' for nil:NilClass

Comment: OK. So I did the include for @properties and the @photos with properties.map ... I replaced the photo call on the details page with <%= image_tag(property.photos.photoname.medium) %> and get this error ... undefined method `photoname' for #<Photo::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f30c45975f8>

Comment: I've updated the code to show what I have currently. It renders the page BUT instead of the picture, it gives the alt ... #<property:0x007f30c5b05cc8>.

Comment: I'd like to give you credit, even though I "technically" wrote my own answer above, because you helped me immensely! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After a **TON** of help from @МалъСкрылевъ, which also had me learning a few new ways of "thinking" this in general, his answer led me to rethink what I was doing and go back to simply starting over and reconstructing what ended up being VERY basic. All I needed to do was make the photo query for the first photo in my loop over the properties. DUH! Here's what I did in case it helps some other poor new Rails developer!

properties_controller.rb

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController

  ......

  def all
    # gets all of the properties and uses will_paginate
    @properties = Property.paginate(page: params[:page])

  ......

end
```

details.html.erb

```
<% @properties.each do |property| %>
<div class="item col-md-4">
  <% @photo = Photo.where(property_id: property.id).order("position").first %>
  <div class="image">
    <%= link_to property_path(property) do %>
      <span class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-file-o"></i> Details</span>
    <% end %>
    <%= image_tag(@photo.photoname.medium) %>
  </div>

  ......
```